# Getting "Objects are not valid as a React child" , im using an array to render a collection of children, but its still not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

As the title says, i am getting this issue when calling the below function

```
const CustomAgenda = () => {
  return <ScrollView>{returnArray()}</ScrollView>;
};
```

It is calling the returnArray function

```
const returnArray = async () => {
  let set = [];
  console.log(6);
  await getJobs().then(() => {
    console.log(7);
    set = j.map(x => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> {x.itemType} </Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  });
  await console.log(set);
};
```

At the end this console.log's the following - Which is what it should be, but im still getting that same error

```
[<View><Text> Carerre </Text></View>, <View><Text> Car </Text></View>, <View><Text> Car </Text></View>, <View><Text> Car </Text></View>, <View><Text> Car </Text></View>]
```

I believe the error could be located in these next two functions

The below function gets job UID from a database, then calls the getJobData function to return the information from each job

```
async function getJobs() {
  console.log(8);
  await firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(global.uid)
    .get()
    .then(async documentSnapshot => {
      console.log(9);
      console.log(10);
      await getJobData(documentSnapshot.get('jobs'));
    });
}
```

The getJobData function pushes the returned data to a global array named 'j'

```
const getJobData = async jobList => {
  for (const i of jobList) {
    let item = {};

    await firestore()
      .collection('Jobs')
      .doc(i)
      .get()
      .then(documentSnapshot => {
        item.id = i;
        item.itemType = documentSnapshot.get('itemType');
        item.size = documentSnapshot.get('size');
        item.type = 'Pickup';
      })
      .then(() => {
        j.push(item);
      });
  }
};
```

The 'j' array returns the following - which is also correct.

```
[{"id": "fST5A2WzgUR66xxNdHAU", "itemType": "Carerre", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "cKQLGqqtyyuxhO7ZuFLR", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "l3KCfGSKh3MCySje832f", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "B8byNmHdc6g5YGqTPovX", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}, {"id": "FQraUtV7uTDyvkux1Vkf", "itemType": "Car", "size": "Large", "type": "Pickup"}]
```

After logging numbers, it seems to be the calling of getJobs, as the logs happen in this order - 6 - error - 8 9 10 7

Thankyou in advanced for any help

Comment: In the ```returnArray``` function you forgot to **return** the ```set``` variable, and the same in the other function - you don't return anything from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `set` in `returnArray`. But that won't matter anyway. You also need to store the result in state anyway (of the data, not the components). You are trying to render a promise, which won't work -- and is the ultimate cause of the error. You need to wait for the data, then store that in state, which will trigger a render.

The `returnArray`  becomes unnecessary with this.

Try this:

```
const CustomAgenda = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      getJobs().then(data => setData(data))
  }, [])

  return <ScrollView>{
            data.map(x=> (
              <View>
                <Text> {x.itemType} </Text>
              </View>
            )}
         </ScrollView>;
};
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend - I have been stuck on this for 12+ hours - Time to do some more research on React Hooks 

I could hug you - Have a good day

Comment: Haha no worries. Yeh essentially you cant just render the return value of a function if its an async function. Youve got to launch the promise (like on mount like this example), then store the result in state, which react then reads from. React wont process promises in render by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally return nothing to your JSX, the corrected function:

```
const returnArray = async () => {
  let set = [];
  console.log(6);
  await getJobs().then(() => {
    console.log(7);
    set = j.map(x => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> {x.itemType} </Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  });
  await console.log(set);
return set
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function name is `returnArray` but in your code the function doesn't return anything. The error appear because you use a function inside a JSX element as child and this function doesn't return an array, because also JSX element allows just array as data inside it.
Try to return array in your function.

```js
const returnArray = async () => {
  let set = [];
  console.log(6);
  await getJobs().then(() => {
    console.log(7);
    set = j.map(x => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> {x.itemType} </Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  });
  await console.log(set);
  return set;
};
```